# Ansible Variable Within square brackets and single quotes [' ']

Tags: variables, ansible, escaping

Hi Guys would anyone be able to advise how I can format a variable within square brackets and single quotes.

Im using inventory groups but wish to have a single var that I can change and be referenced ie

```
_devices:
   - webservers
```

and I would like the var _devices to be used within the following

```
`groups[' ']`
```

so I just have a single entry to change and not the whole play. Struggling to escape `"{{ _devices }}"` with [' ']

ie

```
groups['"{{_ devices }}"']

{% for host in groups['webservers'] %}
{{ hostvars[host][‘ansible_host’] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what is the expected result. Is it the content of a file? If not,[edit] the question and make it [mre].

Comment: edited above thanks

Comment: The `_devices` variable is a list, do you want to iterate over it and get each "item" in `groups[' ']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are conflating a string literal with a variable reference; anytime one finds themselves trying to use nested jinja2 mustaches, it's a bug

Your talk of `[]` means you are expecting `devices` to in fact be a list of group names, in which case you'll want the [`| extract` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) to apply `[groups[g_name] for g_name in devices]` (regrettably jinja2 does not understand list comprehensions like that). Then, because each `extract` run will itself be a `list[str]`, meaning the output will be `list[list[str]]`, but you want just `list[str]`, you'll apply the `|flatten` to fold them up to one list

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      all hosts in devices are: {{ devices | map("extract", groups) | flatten | list }}
  vars:
    devices:
    - webservers
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I've used that to set_fact and used that to get around the Jinja2 issue.